# Installing ubuntu 16.04 LTS about swap

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, live-usb, swap

**How avoid reformatting others swap partitions?**
I have a lot of distro in my hard drive:

- Windows10
- Ubuntu16.10
- Antergos[ Arch Linux]
- Fedora25
- free space
- Data

All Linux distros have swap partitions (16GiB each one).
In the free space first I created a swap partition of 16 GiB and the rest of size is for root partition(ext4).

- /dev/sda13
- /dev/sda14
  [image]

[image]

It is odd that we can't select the swap partitions, anyway click in  "install now" button

[image]

I do not want to reformat those Linux' swap, How avoid that?

*hard drive : 2 TiB MBR

Output of fdisk -l*

ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/loop0: 1.2 GiB, 1246838784 bytes, 2435232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xaaf06e0e

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048  525314047  524288000   250G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        525316094 3907028991 3381712898   1.6T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       2644512768 3907028991 1262516224   602G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6        525316096  557314047   31997952  15.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7        557316096 1057314815  499998720 238.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       1057314817 1058291377     976561 476.9M 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       1058291379 1090291377   31999999  15.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda10      1090291379 1590291377  499999999 238.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda11 *    1590294528 2114582527  524288000   250G 83 Linux
/dev/sda12      2114584576 2148139007   33554432    16G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 8 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 9 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 10 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7742685184 bytes, 15122432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x178e5ca0

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 2538431 2538432  1.2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       2511036 2515771    4736  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$

Comment: Besides having multiple swap partitions, which is nuts, you've got a bigger problem in that 4 of your existing partitions are not properly aligned. This really impacts performance.

Comment: How can we fix that, I only have one important partition /dev/sd5 (Data).

Comment: How can we fix that, I only have one important partition /dev/sd5 (Data) that i can't delete. 
Or I must to delete all hard drive.

Comment: There's two choices. 1) start over. repartition the entire drive, reload software. or restore from previous partition image backups. or 2) **try** to surgically remove the unaligned partitions, replace them with aligned partitions, restoring the data from a previous partition image backup.

Comment: hello, anyone told me when I will be formatting a free space I must select the option "Align to cylinder".  instead of MiB.

Comment: Leave it set at the default of MiB. For a quick test, use `fdisk -l` to see if they're aligned. For an officially correct way, use the `parted align-check` command. Sounds like you're going for the surgical method.

Comment: @heynnema — For me, `parted … align-check minimal` tells me that all partitions are aligned, but `parted … align-check optimal` tells me that some are not aligned. Which is the important one? I know how to "surgically" remove, recreate and restore partitions. When recreating partitions, how can I be sure to align them correctly? Will `gparted` automatically do this correctly if I select align to MiB? Or, can I fix this by merely resizing and shifting each misaligned partition? (Please let me know if I should start a new question for this.) Thank you.

Comment: Technically, fdisk is for MBR disks, and gdisk is for GPT disks, like what you have. I don't know if gdisk will give the same quick alignment info as fdisk, but you could try `gdisk -l /dev/sda`. You may have to check the `man` page. Gparted should align properly on MiB. To be sure, surgically remove one of your misaligned partitions, recreate it, and recheck it with fdisk/parted.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need different swap partitions for different systems, the same way you don't need different RAM sticks for different systems. Just share one between all of them. You should use the left-most one because it's the one with the fastest read/write speed (on a HDD).

The only time something relevant after a shutdown is still on the swap is when you hibernate your PC (suspend to disk). But that's disabled by default, anyway.

Don't care about them getting formatted. If no system is suspended to disk (and only if a swap partition is used to hold the suspension image which isn't necessarily the case), it doesn't change anything.

Formatting a swap partition is a problem if it's auto-mounted using its UUID. To check whether that's the case, open the `/etc/fstab` files of your systems. If there is a line containing the word "swap" which starts with `UUID=`, the UUID has to be exchanged by the new one. Note that there doesn't have to be such a line. Your swap partitions can be identified by their device name. In this case, the line starts for example with `/dev/sda12` and nothing has to be done – except if you deleted the partition or it's now a partition of a different kind, in which case the device name has to be changed.

If you deleted all but one swap partition, write the same UUID into the respective line of the `/etc/fstab` of all of your Linux systems. This can be done either in the live session or in the systems themselves. The change will take effect after you boot the next time. If the UUID changed, the swap partition will not be mounted but apart from there being no swap partition, the system can be used normally.

Comment: hello pal, those ramx have been created by themselves

Comment: then, we can go ahead safely

Comment: I didn't assume you use different RAM bars for different systems. Of course, you don't. It wasn't an allusion to your `/dev/ramX`s, instead I tried to say: "You don't use different RAM bars for different operating systems. A swap partition is an extension of your RAM. So why would you use different swap partitions for different systems?"

Comment: Ah ok pal, I understood you. ram bar= RAM memory stick

Comment: Wouldn't formatting the swap areas change their UUIDs? That's going to be annoying for any system that has UUIDs for the swap entries in their /etc/fstab.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, you're right. If UUIDs are used to identify auto-mounted partitions, that's a problem.

Comment: UUID is the best way. Either way you'll have to edit each fstab to reflect the correct UUID (or /dev/sdan) designation for the swap partition.

Comment: In fact , from my new ubuntu gnome all swap has key http://i.imgur.com/ckExyLX.png

Comment: The key means that the partition is in use. In the live session, the system doesn't know which partitions it should use, so it simply mounts all swap portions and none of the others. This means that in der live session, you have as much swap space as in all of your systems combined. You can check this in the system monitor. Just right-click a swap partition in GParted and choose "swapoff" so the partition isn't being used any more so you can change/delete it. Since the installer wanted to use all swap partitions, you have all of the swap space available in your newly installed system, too.

Comment: this is from Antergos, it has no problem I think http://i.imgur.com/qgcz2Sg.png

Comment: And here from Fedora 25, there is no problem too, i think http://i.imgur.com/cCLDTeW.png

Comment: and one more Ubuntu 16.10 , order of isntallation of the operating systems 1.- windows10, 2.-Ubuntu16.10(swap,root), 3.-Antergos[ Arch Linux](boot,swap,root), 4.-Fedora25(swap,root), 5.-Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04 LTS(swap,root).

Obviously when i installed ubuntu 16.10 there was not any swap partitions, therefore at the end Ubuntu 16.10 only could select and format one swap partitions. http://i.imgur.com/ieFFhB4.png

Comment: What do you mean by "no problem"? Do you mean that the partitions still get mounted in the old systems, even though they were formatted and you didn't modify the `/etc/fstab`s of the old systems? If that's the case: As I said: "Formatting a swap partition is a problem if it's auto-mounted **using its UUID**." Partitions can be auto-mounted without using their UUIDs.

Comment: well , the images says each distro has one swap partitions, except the last one Ubuntu-Gnome16.04 it has three.

Comment: That's what's to be expected. If the old distros identified the swap partitions for example by their device location (e.g. `/dev/sda9`), nothing changed for them. They still use the partition because the identifier they use didn't change. What kind of identifier your newly installed system uses, actually doesn't matter for this result. It just gathered all swap partitions it was able to find, identified them by whatever means it chose to (the identifiers didn't change in any case since it was last at work because it was the last system to change any), and wrote them into its `/etc/fstab`.